# Hibernate - Mapping java.util.Calendar to MySQL BIGINT

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a `Calendar` field in my entity

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private Calendar transmissionDate;
```

which needs millisecond precision. As is, Hibernate generates a schema, mapping this field to a

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | 
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| transmission_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
```

in MySQL. [The `datetime` type in MySQL discards everything after the second](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html), so I lose my precision. The solution I've been using for now is

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long transmissionDate;
```

and generate a Calendar instance from it when it's required.

This is a huge hassle and I want to know if Hibernate has functionality that can overcome it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369460/how-do-i-map-a-hibernate-timestamp-to-a-mysql-bigint) shows how you can use a custom type, but, implementing it, Hibernate is still mapping to a `datetime` column type.

How can I retain the millisecond precision while still using the `Calendar` type in my entity?

Comment: If you're using a more recent version of MySQL (5.6.4+) you can get up to microsecond precision: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: @Muel Any idea how to tell Hibernate to use that precision?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't need to be told anything. It should be as simple as modifying your existing database column, so that it's now `DATETIME(3)` instead of `DATETIME(0)`. Everything else should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using a custom `UserType` that maps a `Calendar` to a `BIGINT`.

```
public class CalendarType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {Types.BIGINT};
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> returnedClass() {
        return Calendar.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names,SessionImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Long timeInMillis = resultSet.getLong(names[0]);
        if (timeInMillis == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
            return calendar;
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) value;
        preparedStatement.setLong(index, calendar.getTimeInMillis());       
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        Calendar calendar = (Calendar) value;       
        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        Long timeInMillis = (Long) cached;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);
        return calendar;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }
}
```

And my Entity then has

```
@TypeDef(name = "calendarType", typeClass = CalendarType.class)
@Entity
@Table
public class Entity {

    @Type(type = "calendarType")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Calendar transmissionDate;

    ...
}
```

Hibernate is god damn magical.

Answer (score 0):

Use Joda [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). You can [map it directly in Hibernate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html) using the [`org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/apidocs/org/joda/time/contrib/hibernate/PersistentDateTime.html) class and it has millisecond precision.

```
@Column
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime transmissionDate;
```

Comment: Joda `DateTime` might have millisecond precision (so does `Calendar`),  but my MySQL version limits the time to seconds. Does the `PersistentDateTime` write to a `datetime`/`timestamp` field or to a BIGINT field?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? Have a look at @Muel's comment

Comment: I'm on 5.5 or something. Even if I was on 5.6.4+, I'd still have to set it, but I'm letting Hibernate generate the schema so how do I force it to use `DATETIME(3)` for instance?