# Hibernate stores Calendar as int when using SQLite

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, date, datetime

I am using Hibernate 4.3.8 along with a SQLite database (sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar). Some of the mapped objects contain `Calendar`-attributes, e.g. `startDate` and `endDate`. After Hibernate got problems with reading dates in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` (e.g. 2015-01-01), I added the following line to hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="connection.date_string_format">yyyy-MM-dd</property>
```

Reading from the database works now, but when I save an object, Hibernate should save the date in the correct format but saves the time in milliseconds since 1970. After that, reading from the database again results in an error, since the columns now have values like `1427410800105`, which are of course not the right format. Btw., I'm using the SQLiteDialect from [here](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java), there should be nothing wrong with that.

Are there maybe some annotations that can help me?

Personally, I only want to change some things in the configuration or in the dialect, I don't want to go through all my objects and do changes there. And of course I don't want to change the type `Calendar` to `Date`, because this would mean too much changes to the code.

**UPDATE:** Using `@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE)` does not work. The column entries stay the same.

**UPDATE2:** The same goes for `@Column(columnDefinition = "calendar")`

Answer (score 0):

<s>After some research I found the [CalendarDateType](http://tool.oschina.net/uploads/apidocs/hibernate-4.1.4/org/hibernate/type/CalendarDateType.html). As I see it, Hibernate stores the `Calendar` attributes as timestamp by default. MySQL seems to convert this to a `DATE` or a `DATETIME`, but as SQLite has no such type, all date values are stored as `TEXT`. Saving a `Calendar` as timestamp results in these ugly numbers.</s> To change the way Hibernate handles `Calendar`, just add the `@Type`-annotation:

```
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.CalendarDateType")
Calendar someAttribute;
```

If the `Calendar` should be saved in another format, you can define your own implementation of `UserType` like in this question: [Hibernate - Mapping java.util.Calendar to MySQL BIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688182/hibernate-mapping-java-util-calendar-to-mysql-bigint)

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use the `CalendarDateType` from Hibernate, but for some reason, it didn't work. A quick look at the source code also shows that Hibernate uses another date format (`dd MMMM yyyy`), so it could make things problematic. To handle this I wrote my own implementation of `UserType` as described in the link above.